# C++ (gcc) Nested template issue?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following simplifications, this works:

```
// works:
template<typename NodeStructure>
struct ListNode {
    NodeStructure *prev, *next;
};

template<typename NodeStructure, ListNode<NodeStructure> NodeStructure::*node>
struct ListBase {
    NodeStructure *head, *tail;
};

struct N {
    ListNode<N> node;
};

struct B {
    ListBase<N, &N::node> base;
};
```

But this not works

```
template<typename NodeStructure>
struct List {

    struct Node {
        NodeStructure *prev, *next;
    };

    template<Node NodeStructure::*node>
    struct Base {
        NodeStructure *head, *tail;
    };

};

struct N {
    List<N>::Node node;
};

struct B {
    List<N>::Base<&N::node> base; // ERROR: Invalid template argument, ¿why?
};
```

In the real code, the List template receives more template parameters and defines an additional class Iterator, the question is ¿why not work, i doing something wrong?

---

OH NO Is a IDE issue !!

**Eclipse CDT / Code analysis false positives when scanning nested template arguments.**

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `List<N>::Node<>` Node is not a class template, is this a typo? `List<N>::Node`

Comment: `List<N>::Node<>` — the `<>` looks redundant, try removing it.

Comment: You are not invoking the template with a member function, but that is what it expects to get.

Comment: @Dave it's expecting a member pointer, and it gets one.

Comment: Oh, ok. Not a syntax I'm familiar with then.

Comment: What error do you get? If you remove the `<>`, as others have advised, ideone compiles this without a hitch.

Comment: Sorry, the angles (<>) have been a copy and paste error. The 'List' template need to receive a pointer to 'node' member of the node structure, not a pointer to any function. Thanks

Comment: Compiler+version? This works at least on some versions of g++.

Comment: Works fine with gcc 4.2.1 and up, as well as clang 4.0 (both C++11 and C++98)

Comment: @VladLazarenko clang 4.0?

Comment: @DyP: `clang++ --version` says `Apple clang version 4.0`, which I am guessing is LLVM 3.1 :)

Comment: @jdavidls: I have just checked with gcc 4.7.2 — works like a champ.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not in the code excerpt you've given. Compiling just the second snippet works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eclipse CDT breaks buildings when detecting code analysis errors. 
Solution: code analisys invalid template arguments has been disabled and a bug reported

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407497