# linked list first member variable of node structure always next node

Tags: c++, linked-list

Suppose you have a linked list of nodes as defined below:

**C++ code**

```
struct node {
    node *next;
    int i ;
};
```

Is there any benefit in making the next pointer as the first member variable of the structure ?

I think that people try this via the above approach (I may be wrong here)

```
node n, m;
*n=&m;
```

If above is right, is it right to code like above. What's the right way?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any benefit in making the next pointer as the first member
>   variable of the structure ?

A very small performance benefit can be reached to reduce the assembly instruction size in loads from and writes to zero offset members, but only in classes without virtual table (vtbl is a omitted first member).

If you want prebuild a scope/global allocated list, its elements can be initialized as mentioned.

You can try it:

```
struct node {
    struct node* next;
    int i;
};

node z = {0}, c={&z}, b={&c}, a={&b};
node * stack = &a;
```

you can find very useful information about liked list searching for 'linux kernel linked list':

- [Linux Kernel Linked List Explained](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)
- [How does the kernel implements Linked Lists?](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LinkedLists)

I  working now in my own design of 'intrusive node' general purpose containers using c++ templates, [perhaps this question might seem interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427928/c-gcc-nested-template-issue).

Comment: intrusive node is a homegrown term

Answer (score 0):

```
node n, m;
*n = &m;
```

is not legal code, perhaps you mean

```
node n, m;
n.next = &m;
```

but normally this would be done with dynamic allocation

```
node* n = new node;
n->next = new node;
```

because normally you would use `node` to create a variable length list. Since the length of the list varies there is no way to declare the right number of variables, instead you must allocate the nodes dynamcally.